# How to declare a variable as const int?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to insert a computed integer into an expression for a Smoothed Moving Average.

I have the following code:

```
float timeframe = str.tonumber(timeframe.period)
float timeframefactor = 5/timeframe

int MA200Factor = math.round(200*timeframefactor)
int MA50Factor = math.round(50*timeframefactor)
int MA20Factor = math.round(20*timeframefactor)
```

I then have followed this up with an SMMA line for length:

```
len200 = input.int(200, minval=1, title="200 SMMA", group = "Smoothed MA")
```

I would like the `MA200Factor` to replace the "200". However, when I do this, it comes up with an error saying the value needs to be `const int`. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Cant do it!!... however I do have a len function that I can substitute a number. Doesnt need to be an input.int(). This solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `const int` means its value must be known at compile time. Therefore you cannot use variables for that argument.